# Missing Plugin when using gst-discoverer

Tags: gstreamer, decoder, python-gstreamer

Getting error when using gst-discoverer script.
Is there any way to get the name?

When set the VERBOSE mode on (`GST_DEBUG=3`) , got the following msgs:

```
basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3583:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet

WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3583:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.106675435   140 0x75e01d50 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux_types.c:233:qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type pasp
0:00:00.106839132   140 0x75e01d50 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:3031:qtdemux_parse_trex:<qtdemux0> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
.....
uridecodebin gsturidecodebin.c:921:unknown_type_cb:<discoverer-uri> warning: No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc,

....
uridecodebin gsturidecodebin.c:988:no_more_pads_full:<discoverer-uri> error: no suitable plugins found:

...
```

Tried installing libav as well
`apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav --no-install-recommends` still no progress.

Not sure if I am missing anything. Can you guys please help me in solving the issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is gstreamer1.0-libav installed?

Comment: yes, i resolved it by installing gstlibav. thanks